# Eclipse long build time for java project

Tags: java, eclipse, build

EDIT: The solution was as follows: Disabling egit solved the building problem. For some reason, egit causes the build process to hang for many minutes.

I have a problem when I need to rebuild my java project. Our project takes 12 minutes to compile with "clean project" in eclipse. It will hang very long on a somewhat random percentage. There should in theory be no buildling cycles, and I have set "Max iterations when building with cycles" to 1 just in case.
I thought I had a nice solution to find out where it stopped: I wrote a small program to analyze the generated .class files too see which class-files it stops on for so long. So I wrote the attached program which sorts the generated .class -files by modifieddate
Guess if I was surprised with the results!
The build started around 12:20:40 and was finished 12:32:40
The first of the 4458 class-files was generated 12:20:42, and the last was generated 12:21:22
So the entire build took 40 seconds. So what the *beep* is eclipse doing those last 11 minutes??

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.*;

public class AnalyzeBuildTime {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    File dir = new File(path_to_project);
    Vector<File> v = new Vector<File>();
    parse(v,dir);
    System.out.println("Nr of files: "+v.size());
    Collections.sort(v,new Comparator<File>() {
        public int compare(File o1, File o2) {
            return new Long(o1.lastModified()).compareTo(o2.lastModified());
        }           
    });
    System.out.println("Listing");
    for (File f : v) {
        System.out.println(f.getName()+"\t"+getTimeString(f.lastModified()));
    }
}

private static void parse(Vector<File> v, File f) throws Exception{
    if (f.isDirectory()) {
        for (File ff : f.listFiles()) {
            parse(v,ff);
        }
    }
    else if (f.getName().endsWith(".class")){
        v.addElement(f);
    }
}

public static String getTimeString(long l){
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTimeInMillis(l);
    return zero(c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY))+":"+zero(c.get(Calendar.MINUTE))+":"+zero(c.get(Calendar.SECOND)); 
}

private static String zero(int i) {
    if (i < 10) return "0"+i;
    return ""+i;
}
}
```

EDIT
Back from vacation, and have tried to understand this some more. I have now tried buildling my workspace via headless building ala:

```
eclipsec.exe -noSplash -application org.eclipse.jdt.apt.core.aptBuild -data c:\workspace
```

This seems to build fine for some time, displaying messages ala "(Found 4345 warnings) Compiling Diverse", then suddenly stops and hangs for about 4-5 minutes before continuing, continuing on "(Found 4346 warnings) Compiling Diverse" as if nothing has happened (and yes, it reaches a different warning count each time..)
Have tried profiling it with jvisualvm, but really does not know what I should be looking for. Some "Compiler Processing Task" threads are spawned in sequence, and the last "Compiler Processing Task" thread seems to be in wait mode when it hangs, with 0ms in "Running", and when the compiling eventually continues, this thread is stopped and a new "Compiler Processing Task" thread starts.
It should be noted that when compiling from command line, it compiles all my projects, and not only the big project that takes so much time from within eclipse, and it seems to be finished with the big 'Pos' project before it hangs on usually 'Diverse' or another project.
I just tried upgrading from eclipse neon to eclipse oxygen, but it seems to have the same behaviour.

EDIT2
Well, I've finally found a "solution", but I'm not that happy with it.
I'm using eclipse Neon (4.6.2), and have also tried switching to oxygen, but the problem persists.
I then tried building my project on my old computer running eclipse mars (4.5.2), and strangely enough did not experiance any build hangs. So I have copied my mars-eclipse from my old computer, and Clean on my big project now takes 55 seconds, and clean all takes 1:15. Still very interested in the reasons for the build hangs, so that I can use newer versions of eclipse.

Comment: Well, since it doesn't seem to be compiling, then what else is it doing? Task Manager / Performance will give you a rough idea of what computer resources are being used. The profiling answer is a good idea; I'm afraid command line compile will just tell you what you already know. You don't need another IDE, and I notice you didn't ask for one. In whatever build process you have, what is it that is done after compiling?

Comment: No it is not a maven project, it is a plain old eclipse java project

Comment: Have you enabled the showing of sleeping and "system" operations in the Progress View? I'm not sure how you're judging the building as taking 12 minutes, but maybe something will show up there?

Comment: Hi @runholen, does your debug mode is also slow to load and run??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** It turned out to be caused by the [EGit](https://eclipse.org/egit/) plugin. The problem went away after disabling it.

(To see the path to debug this kind of performance problem, see the rest of the original answer)

---

There can be several reasons and I don't want to guess. But if you are interested to know what Eclipse is doing, there is a systematic approach to find it out, or at least bring you in a better position to solve the problem:

1. Start Eclipse and attach [VisualVM](https://visualvm.github.io/) to the build process (in your case, Eclipse itself). VisualVM should be part of your JDK installation. If not, you it is freely available for download.
2. Under Threads, there is the "Thread Dump" option, which will create a stack trace of all running threads
3. Trigger the build and from time create thread dumps in VisualVM
4. Analyze the stack traces and look for a pattern (i.e., a stack trace that shows up much more often)

From the stack-traces, you should hopefully see what Eclipse internally does. Statistically, even when you only look only at very few stack traces, it is very likely that it will reveal existing bottlenecks. For instance, I remember situations where it pointed me to specific plugins that I had installed (e.g. FindBugs). Removing them increased the performance again.

If it is still not clear what is going on, you can use the stack traces to add more details to your question, which would allow educated guesses. In the best case, you could even file a bug report. (Especially, when your code base is huge, it is not unlikely to run into bugs).

To show that the technique is effective for finding performance problems in IDEs, I want to mention that IntelliJ automatically dumps stack traces to disk whenever operations hang for a few seconds. They encourage users to file bug reports for performance issues, and ask them to attach the generated stack traces. It demonstrates that the information is very useful for someone who is familiar with the code base (or the code base of a plugin that shows up on top of the stack trace).

The technique is similar to conventional profiling, but it is often more effective in locating the bottleneck, especially if the bottleneck is obvious (which is likely the case in your scenario).

In addition, the stack trace of the slow path is highly useful when you need to ask for help. Analyzing a performance problem without having access to the machine is hard, but looking at a concrete example (given by the stack trace), can be a game changer.

---

Just to be sure, you should first rule out that the Java process is near the memory limit. VisualVM will list the GC activity in the Monitor tab. I don't think it is the problem in your case, but checking stack traces does not make sense if the application is more or less doing permanent garbage collects. In the worst case, it could even be misleading.

---

**Update:** Part of the thread dump, which drew attention to the problem and lead to the guess that EGit could be the problem (here, is the [full thread dump](https://pastebin.com/esXLxS1g)):

```
"Worker-65" #196 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000002a5d2800 nid=0x29534 runnable [0x0000000049f8e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsNativeDispatcher.GetFileAttributesEx0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsNativeDispatcher.GetFileAttributesEx(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileAttributes.get(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileAttributeViews$Basic.readAttributes(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileAttributeViews$Basic.readAttributes(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.util.FileUtils.getFileAttributesBasic(FileUtils.java:662)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.util.FS_Win32.getAttributes(FS_Win32.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.treewalk.FileTreeIterator$FileEntry.<init>(FileTreeIterator.java:365)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.treewalk.FileTreeIterator.entries(FileTreeIterator.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.treewalk.FileTreeIterator.<init>(FileTreeIterator.java:227)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.treewalk.FileTreeIterator.createSubtreeIterator(FileTreeIterator.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.treewalk.AbstractTreeIterator.createSubtreeIterator(AbstractTreeIterator.java:572)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.treewalk.TreeWalk.enterSubtree(TreeWalk.java:1210)
    at org.eclipse.egit.core.RepositoryUtil.canBeAutoIgnored(RepositoryUtil.java:720)
    at org.eclipse.egit.core.Activator$IgnoreDerivedResources$1.visit(Activator.java:646)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.ResourceDelta.accept(ResourceDelta.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.ResourceDelta.accept(ResourceDelta.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.ResourceDelta.accept(ResourceDelta.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.ResourceDelta.accept(ResourceDelta.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.ResourceDelta.accept(ResourceDelta.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.egit.core.Activator$IgnoreDerivedResources.resourceChanged(Activator.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager$1.run(NotificationManager.java:299)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager.broadcastChanges(NotificationManager.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.broadcastPostChange(Workspace.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.endOperation(Workspace.java:1469)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:157)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)

"Worker-60" #191 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000002a5d6800 nid=0x290c0 in Object.wait() [0x0000000049a8f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.ThreadJob.waitForRun(ThreadJob.java:270)
    - locked <0x00000005c2362c50> (a java.lang.Object)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.ThreadJob.joinRun(ThreadJob.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.ImplicitJobs.begin(ImplicitJobs.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.JobManager.beginRule(JobManager.java:307)
    at org.eclipse.egit.core.internal.indexdiff.IndexDiffCacheEntry.waitForWorkspaceLock(IndexDiffCacheEntry.java:466)
    at org.eclipse.egit.core.internal.indexdiff.IndexDiffCacheEntry.access$5(IndexDiffCacheEntry.java:458)
    at org.eclipse.egit.core.internal.indexdiff.IndexDiffCacheEntry$5.updateIndexDiff(IndexDiffCacheEntry.java:516)
    at org.eclipse.egit.core.internal.indexdiff.IndexDiffUpdateJob.run(IndexDiffUpdateJob.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

Comment: I really don't know how to find out what is wrong based on these stack traces, but maybe you can? I have now pasted the stacktraces to pastebin:
Compiling: https://pastebin.com/wnyNNiuD
Hanging: https://pastebin.com/esXLxS1g

Comment: @runholen Hard to tell, both thread dump look quite different. In the first, the compiler is actively doing some work, but in the second one, it does not even show up. I see more IO instead (e.g., "egit" shows up). If there is an obvious performance issue, it should be likely that patterns repeat. For instance, if 90% of the time in spend in a path, on average, you should see that pattern 9 times out of 10. Given the two thread dumps, I don't know which one is the more important one. If the second one is the bottleneck, you could try to disable egit. If it is the first one, it will not help.

Comment: Wow, disabling egit actually solved the problem! :-D buildling is fast again! Please update your answer accordingly so that it shows that disabling egit may solve the problem, I'm awarding your answer now :-)

Comment: @runholen Thanks, I'm glad to hear that! I updated the answer to document the steps to see it. The technique should be useful for other people, too, even if they do not have exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have 4346 warnings? That can't be good. I keep my projects 100% error and warning free. (Rootitootoot, yeah I know.) But that seems to me like it could be significant overhead, registering all those error messages and strings, especially if the code for doing so has a high "Big O" cost, e.g., if each warning checks previously generated warnings for duplicate elements. (I don't know if it does or not.) Might be worth investigating. Warnings could correlate with "stress" for the compilation process in ways that results in delays.

For better understanding the "Clean Project" process, and what the various stages are, I'd first check at the Eclipse community forums. I've found them to be very helpful. If you do so, posting here what you find out there would be helpful to others with the same problem, of course.

Comment: My eclipse workspace contains a lot of code, about 1,2 million lines of code, whereas the biggest project is about 0,7 million lines. The first code is over 10 years old, so we don't have the time to make it 100% warning free on all the old code. I would guess introducing a lot of @Suppresswarning will not speed it up? Anyway, somehow it is also a good thing that those warnings are there, as it gives some sort of status on where it is in compiling. And it is very interesting that it hangs on a different place each time.

Comment: Do you have any plugins like PMD attached to the project? If yes, it can cause delay.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Update "installed" java path in the eclipse.ini file with the given parameter.

-vm
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_131/bin/javaw.exe

Just try and tell me the difference if any found. :-)